# Github download link on pypi

Tags: python, github, pip, pypi

I am trying to add a package to `pypi` but I don't want to upload a file containing the package. I'd rather use a download link pointing to Github.

I've done this with Bitbucket quite easily, but I can't seem to get the proper download link that works for Github. The pypi URL is [mongokit-py3/0.9.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mongokit-py3/0.9.0), and clicking on the download link opens the `*.tar.gz` file.

However, `pip` doesn't see it and https://pypi.python.org/simple/mongokit-py3/ returns a blank list.

What is wrong with the download URL I've given, or is this a bug in PyPi?

Comment: How is this question off topic? I've just re-read the topic guide and don't see anything that would exclude this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Goto the **urls** tab in your pypi account 
https://pypi.python.org/pypiame=PACKAGE_NAME&version=VERSION_NUMBER&:action=urls

You'll see 3 options for Hosting mode

> 1. Do not extract URLs from the long description field - only use URLs explicitly specified below and files uploaded to PyPI (this is> preferred).
> 2. Present URLs extracted from the long description field.
> 3. As above but also ask tools to scrape Homepage and Download URL (slow!)

Choose the 3rd option (by default the 1st one is selected) and it starts showing the link specified in the Download URL field on your `/simple/PACKAGE_NAME` page.